# ASP.NET MVC C# Email Notifications on Submit

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I would like some advice on Sending Email notifications to Users. I am developing a ticket system and would like the user's to get a notification to the email address they provide on the email field. The same should also be replicated when the ticket has come to a closure.

Answer (score 1):

In `app.config` or `web.config` you configure email and password:

```
<configuration>
       <appSettings>
             <add key="FromEmail" value="Your Email. EX: abc@abc.com"/>
             <add key="FromPassword" value="Your Password of Email"/>
       </appSettings>
</configuration>
```

And in button submit method, use this code:

```
        MailMessage mail = new MailMessage();
        SmtpClient SmtpServer = new SmtpClient("Your Server Mail");

        mail.From = new MailAddress(GetAppSetting("FromEmail"));
        mail.To.Add("User Email You Want Send");
        mail.Subject = "Notifications ";
        mail.Body = "Body your mail";
        mail.IsBodyHtml = true;
        SmtpServer.Port = your_port;
        SmtpServer.Credentials = new System.Net.NetworkCredential(GetAppSetting("FromEmail"), GetAppSetting("FromPassword"));
        //SmtpServer.EnableSsl = true;
        try
        {
            SmtpServer.Send(mail);
            MessageBox.Show("Email Sent!", "Information", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Information);
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Error when send mail, Error Code: " + ex.Message);
        }
```

Comment: This is goodm but am not working on a desktop application, rather a web app

Comment: For Desktop Application. You must Add References System.Configuration.

Comment: If you resolve your problem. Please mark Best Answer! Thank you.